# how to execute complex sql query through fromrawsql in asp.net 6

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am making project in asp.net 6 mvc, and i have to execute complex query contain joins, union and all. I want to fetch data from the database. How to do that through "FromSqlRaw"?

We can fetch data through 'FromSqlRaw' from a single table but how to do it if we are fetching data from multiple tables and using joins, union

Comment: You can't. Each `FromSqlRaw` can only represent a single entity.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You Can Use Dapper as M/ORM to connect to database and query to it. if you want to select you can use this Code:

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    var yourVar = await connection.QueryAsync<YourModel>("select * from YourTable Inner Join ...");
}
```

if you want to execute something like Update, Put or some SP you have to use this code :

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    var Numberofaffectedrows = await connection.ExecuteAsync(sqlCommandString);
}
```

by the way, You have to Get Dapper Nuget Package.

Answer (score 0):

> We can fetch data through 'FromSqlRaw' from a single table but how to
> do it if we are fetching data from multiple tables and using joins,
> union

Well, based on your scenario and description, it seems that you would like to execute complex query which involved lot of  SQL JOIN, Union even other SQL functionalities, actually, there might numerous way to implement that, but using SQL views upon your Entity context would be more easier and convenient to execute join and other query, no mater how complex it is.

In order to do that, you can create a SQL view,  the query you would like to write including all of your requirements, then this view would return your expected entity field or property your can say, now create a class based on the field or property you have returned within your view. Finally, introduce that class as `DbSet<YourClass>` in your dbContext,

Now you can, call it from your controller using [`FromSqlRaw`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/sql-queries) and you can set any conditional on your View.

Let’s have a look in practice how we can implement in code snippet,

SQL View:

```cs
CREATE VIEW RunViewInAspNetCore
AS
SELECT Id, Title, Body, Author FROM Post
```

[image]

This should looks like as following:

[image]

Demo Class:

```
public class ComplexTSQLUsingView
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Body { get; set; }
        public string Author { get; set; }
    }
```

DbContext:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
    {

        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options) : base(options)
        {

        }
     
       
        public DbSet<ComplexTSQLUsingView> ComplexTSQLUsingViews { get; set; }
      

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            
        }
    }
```

Controller:

```
public class ComplexTSQLUsingViewController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;

        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;

        public ComplexTSQLUsingViewController(ILogger<HomeController> logger, ApplicationDbContext context)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _context = context;
        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
        {
            var author = "Kiron";
            var sqlQuery = String.Format("SELECT * FROM [RunViewInAspNetCore] WHERE Author ='{0}'", author);
            var sqlresult = _context.ComplexTSQLUsingViews.FromSqlRaw(sqlQuery).ToList();
            return Ok(sqlresult);
        }

    }
```

**Note:** Set additional condition here in `sqlQuery` variable in order to keep clean your view. In addition, property name should be unique and duplicate property name should used Alias and use alias name in C# property.

Output:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try using stored procedures.
You can save your query in  a stored procedure, then call that stored procedure in FromSqlRaw
Example

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE GetEmployeesWithDepartments
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SELECT
        E.EmployeeID,
        E.FirstName,
        E.LastName,
        D.DepartmentName
    FROM
        Employees AS E
    INNER JOIN
        Departments AS D
    ON
        E.DepartmentID = D.DepartmentID;
END
```

Then execute the stored procedure in FromSqlRaw
Example:

```cs
// Define a method to execute the stored procedure
public async Task<IEnumerable<EmployeeDepartmentResult>> GetEmployeesWithDepartmentsAsync()
{

    // Execute the stored procedure using FromSqlRaw
    var results = await _context.EmployeeDepartmentResults
        .FromSqlRaw("EXEC GetEmployeesWithDepartments")
        .ToListAsync();

    return results;
}
```

And make sure `EmployeeDepartmentResult` contains all the fields that will come from the stored procedure

Comment: what if my database has no table name 'EmployeeDepartmentResult' and it is only a view model contain all the field  that store procedure will return?

Comment: Yeah, you can proceed with that. The class 'EmployeeDepartmentResult' was just used as an example. You can use your view model